# Why comparing two values with one variable with NOT Equal to is not working in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare a variable with two values not equal to but is not working

```
if 'Home' or 'Away' not in sku:
    print(sku)
    data = [sku, price]
else:
    print("Error")
```

2nd way

```
if sku!="Home" or sku!="Away":
    print(sku)
    data = [sku, price]
else:
    print("Error")
```

What I am missing here? Why it is passing nevertheless to data=[sku,price] in both cases?

Comment: What kind of variable is sku?

Comment: _if 'Home' or 'Away' not in sku:_ That is not the correct way to test for multiple values.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134).

Comment: It is something like X45XRT a product number

Comment: the first: `'Home' or 'Away' not in sku` converts to `('Home') or ('Away' not in sku)` Which is basically always True because non empty strings are truthy.

Comment: _if sku!="Home" or sku!="Away":_ No matter what value `sku` has, this if statement will _always_ be true.  If sku is "Home" then it doesn't equal "Away"; and if it's "Away" then it doesn't equal "Home".  You should use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: @Paritosh ok but why the 2nd way is not working?!?!

Comment: the second: `sku!="Home" or sku!="Away"` You've made a logical fallacy. `sku`, when equal to Home, is still going to give True for `sku!="Away"` . Read about de Morgan's law, and essentially, the point being, using `not` or `!=` or any negation gets messy, you have to use `and` here, cause the logic is flawed otherwise.

Comment: Somehow every *single* day, this question is asked a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first way `if 'Home' ...` will always evaluate to True so you need some rearranging of your logic:

```
if not ('Home' in sku or 'Away' in sku):
    print(sku)
    data = [sku, price]
else:
    print("Error")
```

In the second way sku will never be both 'Home' and 'Away' which is how your logic currently reads, so this will always be True as well.

```
if sku!="Home" and sku!="Away":
    print(sku)
    data = [sku, price]
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".